# Order of rewrite rules when calling add_rewrite_rule

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am checking the document for add_rewrite_rule at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/, based on its description, it said "Any value in the $after parameter that isn’t ‘bottom’ will result in the rule being placed at the top of the rewrite rules."

If I understand correctly, the following code:

```
  add_rewrite_rule('/rule1/', 'index.php?rule1', 'top');
  add_rewrite_rule('/rule2/', 'index.php?rule2', 'top');
  add_rewrite_rule('/rule3/', 'index.php?rule3', 'top');
```

will cause the rule priority of:

```
rule3(most high)
rule2(second high)
rule1
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that correct?

It's correct that rules with a [`$after`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/#parameters) value of `top` (or anything other than `bottom`) will be placed above all other rules (that have been registered by the time your code runs).

However, the rules would actually be in the same order `add_rewrite_rule()` is called, so as for the ones in question, you would see them in the following order in the generated rewrite rules (that are saved in the database, although could also be written to the `.htaccess` file), hence `rule1` has the highest priority:

```
/rule1/
/rule2/
/rule3/
```

And that's because "top" and "bottom" rules (which are both extra/custom rules) are grouped and merged using `array_merge()` like so: ([see `WP_Rewrite::add_rule()` on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1667))

```php
if ( 'bottom' === $after ) {
    $this->extra_rules = array_merge( $this->extra_rules, array( $regex => $query ) );
} else {
    $this->extra_rules_top = array_merge( $this->extra_rules_top, array( $regex => $query ) );
}
```

PS: `add_rewrite_rule()` calls `WP_Rewrite::add_rule()`.

### Example 1

- PHP:

  ```php
  add_action( 'init', function () {
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule1/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule1', 'top' );
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule2/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule2', 'top' );
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule3/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule3', 'top' );
  } );

  add_action( 'init', function () {
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule1b/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule1b', 'bottom' );
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule2b/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule2b', 'bottom' );
  } );
  ```
- A `var_dump()` of the generated/saved rules:

  ```
  array(101) {
    ["^wp-json/?$"]=>
    string(22) "index.php?rest_route=/"
    ... other core REST API rules.
    ["^wp-sitemap\.xml$"]=>
    string(23) "index.php?sitemap=index"
    ... other core sitemaps rules.
    ["^rule1/?$"]=>
    string(32) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule1"
    ["^rule2/?$"]=>
    string(32) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule2"
    ["^rule3/?$"]=>
    string(32) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule3"
    ... category, tag, etc. rules.
    ["(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$"]=>
    string(29) "index.php?pagename=$1&page=$2"
    ["^rule1b/?$"]=>
    string(33) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule1b"
    ["^rule2b/?$"]=>
    string(33) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule2b"
  }
  ```

### Example 2

- PHP:

  ```php
  add_action( 'init', function () {
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule1/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule1', 'bottom' );
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule2/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule2', 'bottom' );
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule3/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule3', 'bottom' );
  } );

  add_action( 'init', function () {
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule1b/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule1b', 'top' );
      add_rewrite_rule( '^rule2b/?$', 'index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule2b', 'top' );
  } );
  ```
- A `var_dump()` of the generated/saved rules:

  ```
  array(101) {
    ["^wp-json/?$"]=>
    string(22) "index.php?rest_route=/"
    ... other core REST API rules.
    ["^wp-sitemap\.xml$"]=>
    string(23) "index.php?sitemap=index"
    ... other core sitemaps rules.
    ["^rule1b/?$"]=>
    string(33) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule1b"
    ["^rule2b/?$"]=>
    string(33) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule2b"
    ... category, tag, etc. rules.
    ["(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$"]=>
    string(29) "index.php?pagename=$1&page=$2"
    ["^rule1/?$"]=>
    string(32) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule1"
    ["^rule2/?$"]=>
    string(32) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule2"
    ["^rule3/?$"]=>
    string(32) "index.php?pagename=foo&bar=rule3"
  }
  ```

So as you could see, in both examples, `rule1` is always *before* `rule2` and `rule3`, and `rule1b` is also always *before* `rule2b`.

Comment: Thank you very much!